# find all objects that belong to a relationship from an Array of NSManagedObjects

Tags: iphone, ios, sql, ipad, core-data

I have an array of NSManagedObjects. Lets call it Items. There are two more entities called Group and SubGroup. I have many to one relationship between Items and Group and Items and SubGroup. So an Item can belong to one group and one group object can point to all the item objects in that group.

```
  Items
    ------
    group <<---> Group
    subgroup <<---> SubGroup
```

Based on user choice I have queried the Db and I have list of items that match the query.Lets call it resultArray which stores all Items objects.
 Query was executed on Items entity.
 I also need to show the details (count, name) of groups and subgroups that are associated with Item objects in resultArray.

The brute force method would be to traverse and use a dictionary to find unique
 Group and SubGroup objects. I am sure there would be a better approach, then this, just not able to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
NSArray *items = ...; // your array of Item objects
NSArray *groups = [items valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.group"];
```

Using "Key-Value Coding", it returns a unique list of groups that are related to the
given items.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Saved the day :)